# One Action Client to Many Action Servers

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if is it possible to set a **single action client to many action servers** configuration, such that I can broadcast a specific action type to many servers in the same action namespace.

The number of servers is variable and can grow significantly. So, it is undesired to have one action client for each action server in the client central node.

Each server will accept only related actions via a filter.

So, is there a way to set **actionlib** to keep controlling actions in such configuration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243145/one-action-client-to-many-action-servers/) by [adrianohrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/27906/adrianohrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guesstimate answer: Maybe. The major problem will be that action clients manage individual action requests. So, if there are suddenly multiple replies (this includes one accepting an action, but 5 others rejecting), it is probably going to be confused. If you can guarantee that not happening (maybe via a small filter), you can put a broadcast 1:n node in between, where all relevant client topics are relayed to multiple servers.
Treat with a lot of care, though!

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adrianohrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/27906/adrianohrl/) on 2016-09-06**:
I've already tried to do that, however I got this message:

[ WARN] [1473172754.170846958]: processStatus: Previously received status from [/robotino1/system_robot_interface_node], but we now received status from [/p3_dx/system_robot_interface_node]. Did the ActionServer change?